# Why does subreport only get one row from a JsonDataSource when using subDataSource()?

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a clean Jasper report that calls a subreport with no filter.
In that subreport I show all the Json data (10 rows), and if I see the preview it works: [Subreport preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKEHQ.png).

The problem is when I call the subreport from the main (and clean) report. It only has in the detail the professionalName and the subreport. It should show the professionalName and all the subReport (all 10 rows each time), but it's not the case. It only shows the current row, and I'm sure it's because the main report is not giving all the datasource to the subreport, only that row. Here is the capture: [Main report preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xICQ0.png).

The Data Source Expression is:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

and the Json file is this one:

```
[   {
        "appointmentId": 153,
        "startDate": 1503061200000,
        "patientId": 417,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "85471254B"
        },
        "episodeId": 500358,
        "chn": "500058",
        "patientName": "Aida Mascaró",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "NEUROLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 45,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Neurologia"
        },
        "professionalName": "a",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1387,
            "name": "PRIVADOS"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Privados"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Accidente de trabajo"
        },
        "appoState": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Atendiendo"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503057809579
    },
    {
        "appointmentId": 150,
        "startDate": 1503039600000,
        "patientId": 405,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "40295204D"
        },
        "episodeId": 500349,
        "chn": "500046",
        "patientName": "Cristina Mayo Saez",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "ENDOCRINOLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 28,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Nutrición"
        },
        "professionalName": "b",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1387,
            "name": "PRIVADOS"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Privados"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {},
        "appoState": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Atendiendo"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503037036812
    }, {
        "appointmentId": 151,
        "startDate": 1503039600000,
        "patientId": 416,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "18466341D"
        },
        "episodeId": 500350,
        "chn": "500057",
        "patientName": "Gloria Sena Arrayán",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "NEUROLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 45,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Neurologia"
        },
        "professionalName": "b",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1396,
            "name": "AGRUPACION MUTUAL ASEGURADORA (AMA)"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Trafico"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {},
        "appoState": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Atendido"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503038643436
    },  {
        "appointmentId": 154,
        "startDate": 1503298800000,
        "patientId": 389,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "23234567J"
        },
        "episodeId": 500359,
        "chn": "500030",
        "patientName": "maria perez perez",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "ENDOCRINOLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 28,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Nutrición"
        },
        "professionalName": "a",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1387,
            "name": "PRIVADOS"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Privados"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Accidente causal"
        },
        "appoState": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Atendiendo"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503297627789
    }, {
        "appointmentId": 148,
        "startDate": 1503300600000,
        "patientId": 415,
        "episodeId": 500346,
        "chn": "500056",
        "patientName": "Pastora Meseguer Carrión",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "NEUROLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 45,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Neurologia"
        },
        "professionalName": "a",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1387,
            "name": "PRIVADOS"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Privados todos"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "No requerida"
        },
        "reason": {},
        "appoState": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Atendido"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1502885871664
    },  {
        "appointmentId": 152,
        "startDate": 1503302400000,
        "patientId": 416,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "18466341D"
        },
        "episodeId": 500351,
        "chn": "500057",
        "patientName": "Gloria Sena Arrayán",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "NEUROLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 46,
        "benefitName": "REVISION",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Neurologia"
        },
        "professionalName": "a",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1396,
            "name": "AGRUPACION MUTUAL ASEGURADORA (AMA)"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Trafico"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {},
        "appoState": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Atendido"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503038674027
    },{
        "appointmentId": 156,
        "startDate": 1503302400000,
        "patientId": 389,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "23234567J"
        },
        "episodeId": 500361,
        "chn": "500030",
        "patientName": "maria perez perez",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "PEDIATRIA",
        "benefitId": 3,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 29,
            "name": "Dra. De la Vega"
        },
        "professionalName": "a",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1387,
            "name": "PRIVADOS"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Privados"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "observations": "obs",
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Accidente causal"
        },
        "appoState": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Atendiendo"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503300374408
    },{
        "appointmentId": 142,
        "startDate": 1503298800000,
        "patientId": 412,
        "episodeId": 500337,
        "chn": "500053",
        "patientName": "Mariano López Pastor",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "NEUROLOGIA",
        "benefitId": 45,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "Neurologia"
        },
        "professionalName": "b",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1387,
            "name": "PRIVADOS"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Privados todos"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "No requerida"
        },
        "reason": {},
        "appoState": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Atendido"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1502877885393
    },  {
        "appointmentId": 158,
        "startDate": 1503303300000,
        "patientId": 408,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "123123"
        },
        "episodeId": 500363,
        "chn": "500049",
        "patientName": "ANA CARO MARTINEZ",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "PEDIATRIA",
        "benefitId": 3,
        "benefitName": "CONSULTA",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 29,
            "name": "Dra. De la Vega"
        },
        "professionalName": "b",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1749,
            "name": "ADMIRAL INSURANCE"
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Trafico"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "observations": "dewdfe",
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Solicitada"
        },
        "reason": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Accidente causal"
        },
        "appoState": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Atendiendo"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503301904789
    }, {
        "appointmentId": 159,
        "startDate": 1503304200000,
        "patientId": 48,
        "patientIdentification": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "1425871"
        },
        "episodeId": 500364,
        "chn": "186",
        "patientName": "cayetana jimenez brotons",
        "centerName": "HOSPITAL CLINICA BENIDORM",
        "serviceName": "PEDIATRIA",
        "benefitId": 4,
        "benefitName": "REVISION",
        "schedule": {
            "id": 29,
            "name": "Dra. De la Vega"
        },
        "professionalName": "b",
        "insurance": {
            "id": 1390,
            "name": "MAPFRE ESPAÑA, CIA. DE SEGUROS Y REASEGUROS S.A."
        },
        "collective": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "MAPFRE SALUD"
        },
        "typeId": 1,
        "observations": "dfd",
        "guarantorStatus": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "No requerida"
        },
        "reason": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Accidente causal"
        },
        "appoState": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Atendiendo"
        },
        "appoType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Simple"
        },
        "professionalCreationName": "Marisol Fernández Lleras",
        "creationDate": 1503301999486
    }
]
```

What can I do to pass the whole DataSet for each row I show? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`subDataSource`](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JsonDataSource.java#L463) method uses the current node when creating a new `JsonDataSource` instance. A future version of JasperReports will address this issue, but until then, you need to:

1. Remove the `Data Source Expression` from your subreport. The subreport itself is going to use a JSON data adapter.
2. Export your JSON data adapter to file. See step #2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584650/5882963) in case you haven't done it before in Jaspersoft Studio.
3. In your subreport, set the report's `Default Data Adapter` property to point to your saved adapter from previous step. See step #4 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584650/5882963).
4. Recompile your subreport if you're note building the project automatically.