# Add sub-report that obtains data from same data source as the master report

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a master report that is composed of tree sub-reports. My datasource is a JSON. Two of them use a nested object in the JSON. While the third one is a sub-report that uses the first level object and inside the sub-report there's other sub-report that uses one of the nested objects.

Everything works, except that the last sub-report (the one with other sub-report) does not render in the pdf. But the .jasper file shows everything perfectly.

I suspect the issue might be here in the Master, but I tried using .subDataSource("data") and did not work.

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["PaymentDetails.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

**Here if my master source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Master" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4f5fe1d5-cd4c-40e9-84cb-283072ae1080">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterDummyJSON.xml"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[data]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="idcNumber" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="idcNumber"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[idcNumber]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cesco" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="cesco"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cesco]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="digitalExpirationDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="digitalExpirationDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[digitalExpirationDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="licenseRenewalDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="licenseRenewalDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[licenseRenewalDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="reportCreationDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="reportCreationDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[reportCreationDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="firstName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lastName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="realId" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="realId"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[realId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="requiredDocuments" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="requiredDocuments"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[requiredDocuments]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesCount" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesCount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesCount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesTotal"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesTotal]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lateFees" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lateFees"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lateFees]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesDiscount" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesDiscount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesDiscount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="totalPayment" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="totalPayment"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[totalPayment]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="transactionReceipt" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="transactionReceipt"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[transactionReceipt]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="charges" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="charges"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[charges]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="77" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1" y="8" width="125" height="55" uuid="5a5eb6db-21f4-4b5f-9300-0548557abcf5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/ImageAssets/Logo_CESCO_Black_300-01.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="481" y="0" width="72" height="72" uuid="98c2d26d-807e-4b19-883a-c6bff6fdf73c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/QR_Code_Example.svg/1200px-QR_Code_Example.svg.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1" y="8" width="125" height="55" uuid="e10d2e29-5aad-43a9-8d2f-5c83ae03f97c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/ImageAssets/Logo_CESCO_Black_300-01.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="481" y="0" width="72" height="72" uuid="ee058ffd-c593-4b2c-b881-090fc5609564">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/QR_Code_Example.svg/1200px-QR_Code_Example.svg.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="47" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="15" width="595" height="30" uuid="0bb6a402-68b5-4219-9b02-6ebe161a9541"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RENOVACIÓN LICENCIA DE CONDUCIR]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    #Removed some code

                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CATEGORÍA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="319" y="148" width="12" height="19" uuid="9f3ecc36-81ae-47b3-9ea3-b4dcc512c0ed">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[3]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="226" y="167" width="80" height="19" uuid="d354a581-b0c4-4bf4-8c7d-69d074a68a55">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REAL ID:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="291" y="166" width="27" height="19" uuid="23265294-9d3e-4477-95b0-e909a00c94cb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{realId}==true? "Sí":"No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="149" width="165" height="19" uuid="1e9fa600-6ec5-4c51-aa75-dbf1baf0141f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[EXPIRACIÓN LICENCIA²: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="165" width="100" height="19" uuid="2e0ebfac-95d6-42fa-a2cf-d66239ce7cb1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[03.28.2020]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="227" width="552" height="22" uuid="d9bad373-99d0-4c17-93d0-fd3b344ea75e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Este comunicado también ha sido enviado a su correo electrónico. ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="262" width="552" height="22" uuid="65d43d45-15cc-4583-b692-fa3134371d23">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Documentos necesarios para el recogido de la licencia:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="304" width="200" height="200" uuid="c02143c5-340d-4ea3-9273-6943e1c584d4"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("requiredDocuments")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["RequiredDocuments.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="527" width="489" height="30" uuid="3f6f6d12-3927-44cc-b9f3-14209f477ad7">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[De no tener algunos de estos documentos favor de seguir las instrucciones adjuntas. ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="267">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" uuid="609a4eec-e75a-4a28-8581-68143de0ca0f"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("requiredDocuments")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Instructions.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="327">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" uuid="1b33f2fc-6d44-4325-a789-0fc342a008ff"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["PaymentDetails.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="273"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Here is the sub-report:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PaymentDetails" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0dc66f1e-e4eb-4e3d-8d6c-ae4885e87beb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterDummyJSON.xml"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[data]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="idcNumber" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="idcNumber"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[idcNumber]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cesco" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="cesco"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cesco]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="digitalExpirationDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="digitalExpirationDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[digitalExpirationDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="licenseRenewalDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="licenseRenewalDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[licenseRenewalDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="reportCreationDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="reportCreationDate"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[reportCreationDate]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="firstName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lastName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="realId" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="realId"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[realId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="requiredDocuments" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="requiredDocuments"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[requiredDocuments]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesCount" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesCount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesCount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesTotal"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesTotal]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lateFees" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lateFees"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lateFees]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="finesDiscount" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="finesDiscount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[finesDiscount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="totalPayment" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="totalPayment"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[totalPayment]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="transactionReceipt" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="transactionReceipt"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[transactionReceipt]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="charges" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="charges"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[charges]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="78" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="20" width="550" height="30" uuid="9ce0ef48-484d-47ab-bf80-d0bb95fd1088">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RENOVACIÓN LICENCIA DE CONDUCIR]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="394" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="64" y="43" width="180" height="19" uuid="f08338a2-802f-4364-acd2-27b71f9d7471">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total de Multas Pagadas]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <ellipse>
                <reportElement x="417" y="35" width="35" height="35" backcolor="#000000" uuid="1c9546ef-1912-4bd7-8262-a98eb975a369">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </ellipse>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="418" y="42" width="33" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0a905bc6-f610-473b-a072-82b4fedbe3df"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{finesCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="86" width="595" height="194" forecolor="#E7EAF3" backcolor="#E7EAF3" uuid="54b7e75d-d7bf-49b6-9e3b-4f31e55b83f0"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="105" width="144" height="20" uuid="47909c9c-799b-49aa-8729-5ca6c67253e8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL MULTAS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="105" width="132" height="20" uuid="27d867e0-05ad-441c-9fc9-6c15cc880f16">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$"+ new DecimalFormat("0,000.00").format($F{finesTotal})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="125" width="144" height="20" uuid="b827a62f-0a49-4ccd-9e16-19a774cc7160">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL RECARGOS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="125" width="132" height="20" uuid="d85a9481-6155-49c6-b6ce-702fcdaa1d28">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true" isStrikeThrough="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$"+ new DecimalFormat("0.00").format($F{lateFees})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="146" width="144" height="20" uuid="10fe7f0c-1150-4f81-b4ac-8a1e4af1d436">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DESCUENTO]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="146" width="132" height="20" uuid="0afe46fe-e810-4814-b097-7516857e3d4a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$"+ new DecimalFormat("0,000.00").format($F{finesDiscount})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="170" width="595" height="60" uuid="3dd7434b-6819-47b1-a8ac-f06ae115a79b"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("charges")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Charges.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="252" width="144" height="20" uuid="7f82cf48-5018-4599-b347-1dc8c2d526db">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="252" width="132" height="20" uuid="8ad2b87b-dd19-4805-a209-627bdfade9c2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$"+ new DecimalFormat("0,000.00").format($F{totalPayment})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="19" y="300" width="53" height="19" uuid="897df478-65c7-4c00-8329-2e1aa4e6aa49">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[FECHA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM.dd.yyyy">
                <reportElement x="75" y="300" width="100" height="19" uuid="0664dddc-1ac7-4c4f-b4be-f39a03f783a7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="320" width="170" height="19" uuid="0db8a6d8-eec7-4823-aacd-21231b060fd7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RECIBO TRANSACCIÓN:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="195" y="319" width="85" height="19" uuid="f1228671-c223-4289-b5fa-7981036edcc4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{transactionReceipt}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="303" width="70" height="19" uuid="a099e44b-9331-471a-91b1-10b5fbdc1b87">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[MOTIVO:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="319" width="260" height="19" uuid="dada3803-b9bc-40f2-8e00-61901fbc3d40">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Renovación de Licencia de Conducir]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**And this is the JSON File I'm using:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "idcNumber": 1234567890123,
    "cesco": "Sagrado Corazón",
    "digitalExpirationDate": "2020-04-07 09:27:45",
    "licenseRenewalDate": "2020-04-07 09:27:45",
    "reportCreationDate": "2020-04-07 09:27:45",
    "firstName": "Hermanegildo M.",
    "lastName": "Maldonado Rodríguez",
    "realId": true,
    "requiredDocuments": [
      {
        "documentNumber": 1,
        "title": "Este Documento Impreso o Digital",
        "instruction": ""
      },
      {
        "documentNumber": 2,
        "title": "Licencia Actual",
        "instruction": ""
      },{
        "documentNumber": 3,
        "title": "Seguro Social / Pasaporte",
        "instruction": "<b"
      },{
        "documentNumber": 4,
        "title": "Recibo Agua, Luz, etc.",
        "instruction": ""
      },{
        "documentNumber": 5,
        "title": "Foto y Firma Digitalizada",
        "instruction": "En "
      }

    ],
    "finesCount": 25,
    "finesTotal": 15000.00,
    "lateFees": 60.00,
    "finesDiscount": 3000.00,
    "totalPayment": 12022.00,
    "transactionReceipt": 120459593030,
    "charges": [
      {
        "chargeName": "Renovación Digital",
        "chargeAmount": 11.00
      },
      {
        "chargeName": "Renovación",
        "chargeAmount": 11.00
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to reuse the same data adapter in your third subreport since it does not seem to be related to the master one. The necessary steps are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47353452/5882963).

Another solution would be to switch to [`JSONQL`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html) for the query language, instead of JSON. This would allow you to navigate up in the JSON tree when constructing new instances of the data source with the `subDataSource()` method.

Comment: I went to the sub-report and added a default data adapter from an absolute path (the same used by master) and in the master deleted the <dataSourceExpression> line. This did not work. I tried to use JSONQL in the master for the query language, but it did not compile giving an error on the other reports <dataSourceExpression> .subDataSource

Comment: On your first attempt, did you also recompile the subreport? That is essential. When switching to JSONQL you also need to use the `JsonQLDataSource` when casting, and the `net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression` variants for textfield properties in order for it  to work.

Comment: Now I changed all reports languages to JSONQL, all the fields have the net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression and the <dataSourceExpression> was changed to include the JSONQL. However, did this not work, everything was re compiled also.

Comment: In the master report, what data source expression do you have now for the subreport that requires the "data" JSON tree?