# Java generate jasperReport from JSON file

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I'm struggling with generating JasperReport using Java. DataSource is not taken into account, so all the values are null and subReport is not shown.

I've created JSONDataAdapter with option 'Use the report JSON expression when filling the report' from the JSON pasted below. When compiling it from Jasper Studio it is creating report correctly, while trying to compile it from Java leads to empty report (only field names shown) without subReport at all. 
Please help with this issue.

```
{
  "user": {
      "firstName": "Mike",
      "lastName": "Jones",
      "email": "mikeJones@gmail.com",
      "userStatus": "VALIDATED",
      "documentList": [
          {
          "id": 2,
          "documentType": "DRIVING_LICENSE",
          "documentStatus": "APPROVED",
          "comment": "",
          "events": [
            {
              "action": "APPROVE",
              "comment": "",
              "createDate": "2018-05-24T10:44:55.987+0000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "documentType": "PASSPORT",
          "documentStatus": "APPROVED",
          "comment": "",
          "events": [
            {
              "action": "APPROVE",
              "comment": "",
              "createDate": "2018-05-24T10:44:55.901+0000"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

main.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_7" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ed8211ff-fccf-451c-9a4e-0b2075ebdfee">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapter1.xml"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[user]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="firstName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lastName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="email"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[email]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="userStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="userStatus"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[userStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="documentList" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentList"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentList]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-7" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="85f69194-56d8-413f-a550-1884c6c2ffdd">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="03de927f-90a6-4a3b-b435-78f511e83566"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[firstName]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="99" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="97a45c99-e11f-466e-83a9-0ee3125a888a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="e2dcce70-e78a-454f-897b-5961f5b060d7"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[lastName]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="277" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-10" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d2158da3-7029-46b7-87e5-73dff198aa5c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="03de927f-90a6-4a3b-b435-78f511e83566"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="ffe6c4e3-0584-4ff0-bb85-8bc1c586424f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="e2dcce70-e78a-454f-897b-5961f5b060d7"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-7" y="30" width="557" height="60" uuid="05a4dede-97de-4836-9195-114755ff921a"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("documentList")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

subreport.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f841d01d-b1ed-4398-9c3a-85751cabd974">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapter1.xml"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[user.documentList]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="id"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="documentType" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentType"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="documentStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentStatus"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="comment" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="comment"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comment]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="events" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="events"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[events]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-7" y="5" width="100" height="30" uuid="b904bfb3-ac61-4141-bbd4-813aa6101945"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="3" width="100" height="30" uuid="85c25658-8388-4eb0-ae5b-b376ce801d0f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String pathToReports = "/home/test/";
      Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
      params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_DATE_PATTERN, "yyyy-MM-dd");
      params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_NUMBER_PATTERN, "#,##0.##");
      params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_LOCALE, Locale.ENGLISH);
      params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US);
      JRDataSource jsonDataSource = new JsonDataSource(new File("/home/test/example.json"));
      JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathToReports + "main.jrxml");
      JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(pathToReports + "subreport.jrxml", "subreport.jasper");

      JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, jsonDataSource);

      JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/home/test/test.pdf");

    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your report is empty when run from Java code because you don't have a Default Data Adapter. It is different from Jaspersoft Studio's one. Either set it:

- like in [this answer's 4th step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584650/5882963)
- or directly with the report level property:

  `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="DataAdapter1.xml"/>`

Comment: I'm sorry, couldn't try it earlier. I set the report level property and now I'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLContext.setClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
Could you help with it as well?

Comment: You need to check you have the appropriate versions of JasperReports' dependencies according to the version you use.